# LINQ to SQL Inheritance Pros and Cons

Tags: .net, database, linq-to-sql, inheritance

I'm designing a game based around Linq2SQL engine.

The game among other objects has Users and NPC's (non-playing characters).

Users and NPC's have somewhat different capabilities, but they also have some common properties, like amount of health or damage.

The activities are done via methods like `void AttackUser(User attacker, User target)`.

The problem here is that NPC's can also attack Users and other NPC's, and Users can attack NPC's, so I will have to write quite a few additional methods and overloads (e.g. `void AttackNpc(User attacker, Npc npc)`.

I can simplify all this by using the inheritance feature of Linq2SQL, with 1 universal table Creatures instead of Users and NPC's separately. This will also allow me to have one universal method, `void Attack (Creature attacker, Creature target)` instead of multiple versions.

On the other hand, inheritance in Linq2SQL seems to greatly increase overall complexity of the solution. Each time I decide to make changes to Users or NPC's, I will need to consider the inheritance issues. Also, with inheritance in Linq2SQL I don't have that clarity of separate tables for Users and NPC's because everything is being dumped into one table. And finally, I'm concerned regarding performance of such combined Creatures table.

It becomes difficult to decide whether I should or shouldn't use inheritance here, because if I choose a suboptimal approach, it's going to be very difficult to switch to another approach in the future.

I'd like to hear expert opinions on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Each time I decide to make changes to Users or NPC's, I will need to
>   consider the inheritance issues.

yes, but if they have a lot in commmon that is also helpful since you do not need to do the changes twice. So iy you are not using inheritance you need to consider the duplication issues.

> Also, with inheritance in Linq2SQL I don't have that clarity of
>   separate tables for Users and NPC's because everything is being dumped
>   into one table.

Well, you are using Linq2SQL to have an abstraction from your database design, so "who cares" in the end. Assuming you have a "type" field you can still create a User and NPC `view` if you really need it.

> And finally, I'm concerned regarding performance of such combined
>   Creatures table.

Assuming you are using sql server you'll need a hell of a lot of creatures before you get into trouble as long as you pay attention to proper indexing

In short, I would go for inheritance